# My text is moving off my image as I re-size my web browser?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My text is moving off my image as I re-size my web browser. I have been searching on Google for the answer, but I have yet find a definitive.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mulk/tzupe2d5/10/#&togetherjs=Ek4Og9VFHK

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid myclass">
<div class="row">
<div  class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12 ">
<img  class="img-responsive compimage" src="http://i1074.photobucket.com/albums/w407/Mulk_Abdulhadi/cop7_zpsqrstboer.jpg">

<div ><h2>Front-End Developer<p>ART/FUN/LIFE</p></h2></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


CSS 
.myclass{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.compimage {
     max-width: 100vw;
   margin-left: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;

}

div h2{
  position: absolute;
 text-align: center;

  color: white;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 55px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed you the problem ! Here's [how to make text responisve](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/Lmsdmxwc/)***

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/LhgOs1W.jpg");
}
div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 10vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  padding: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Front-End Developer</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure exactly what you mean but this is what I did. Let me if your looking for something different.

Add `top: 50px;` and set width to 100% to the `<h2>` text.

here it is in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/King_Code/hL6b4qxh/1/

```
div h2{
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  float: right; 
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 150%;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use font-size:100% , or font-size: 6em. Word breaks/wraps also will help you in general.

EDIT: word-break: break-word;    - on the divider +  width: 100%;  <-- not sure if the width matters or not.

EDIT #2:
Seems like what you actually want is to add style="width:100%;" to the image, then in your css play with these settings

```
  font-size: 5rem;
  top:0px !important;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  padding-left:20%;
  padding-right:20%;
  padding-top:5%;
```

Comment: word-break: break-all;  worked in your fiddle i just did with you :)

Comment: it is still not fixed on the image. Thank for your help

Comment: oh ok one moment while i look

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn your text into an image to be responsive along side the background, or add the text to your back ground image :)

Comment: I am going to try this